# Where to post supplementary drawings?

Tags: support, images, posts

I have a question to post on stack exchange physics but a picture is worth a thousand words. What is the preferred site to use for uploading supplementary drawings that clarify my question? Should I just embed my drawing in the post I make or should I use imgur, etc and insert a link in my post?

Answer (score 5):

Use the Stack Exchange Imgur account as much as possible. Images are kept there, even with low views.

You can use the Stack Exchange Imgur account just by using the Upload button in the post editor:

> [image]